# Proof that ideal inclusion as sets is preserved under localisation of a commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

I apologise if this seems too trivial which is why I am a bit suspicious.

I essentially need to prove that given ideals $I, J$ in a commutative ring $A$, $I \subset J$ iff $I_m \subset J_m$ in $A_m$, for all maximal ideals $m$ in $A$.

I proceeded as thus : Supposing $I \subset J $, take $\frac{x}{s} \in I_m$, where $x \in I$, $\implies x \in J$, $\implies \frac{x}{s} \in J_m$.

Conversely if $I_m \subset J_m$ in $A_m$, then take $x \in I$, $\implies \frac{x}{s} \in I_m, \implies \frac{x}{s} \in J_m$ and consequently $x \in J$.

Is this all there is to it??Or are there any loopholes that I havent been able to perceive??

Comment: In general, $\tfrac{x}{1}\in J_m$ does not imply $x\in J$; e.g., if $xs\in J$, then $\tfrac{x}{1}\in J_m$ even if $x\not \in J$. For the rest of the question, I'm sure this has been answered before multiple times.

Comment: Okay, I can't find a suitable post of which this would count as a duplicate (right now?).

Comment: I'll post a self-contained answer later. (Unless someone else is quicker, everyone is encouraged to post an answer instead.)

Comment: If you want to go on trying, here's a minor hint: make sure to use the assumption that $I_m\subset J_m$ holds for **all** maximal ideals, not just one. Note that the above attempt only involved one maximal ideal instead; if it looks like this, there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Ok, so going by your hint, if I take $m$ as any maximal ideal containing J in particular, then $s \notin J \subset m$ , so if $x \notin J$, $x/s \notin J$ either, which contradicts that $I_m \subset J_m$, for all maximal $m$. Am I right?

Comment: To draw this conclusion, you'd have to assume that $J$ is prime, unfortunately. Here is a more concrete hint: consider the ideal $\{a\in A\mid aJ\subset I\}$ to reduce the problem to the case where $J = A$, i.e., that $I_m = A_m$ for all $m$ implies $I = A$. The latter case can be proven by considering an $m$ containing $I$.

Comment: I got the flaw in my argument, but struggling with that hint. You want me to look at $I:J$, but why reduce it to $J=A$. I am sorry, maybe I am missing something elementary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in the OP's argument was discussed in the comments.
Let give a proof (which differs from the one proposed in the comments which I think needs some finiteness-assumptions on the ideals; I was assuming $A$ is noetherian, I guess).

Given ideals $I,J\subset A$ such that $I_m \subset J_m\subset A_m$ for each maximal ideal $m\subset A$ we claim that $I\subset J$.

Let $f\in A$ be an arbitrary element and consider the ideal $(J:f) = \{a\in A\mid af\in J\}$.
If $S\subset A$ is a multiplicative subset, then $f\in S^{-1}J$ holds if and only if $S\cap(J:f)\neq\emptyset$.
In particular, if $m\subset A$ is a maximal ideal, then $f\in J_m$ if and only if $(J:f)$ is not(!) contained in $m$.
Consequently, if $f\in J_m$ for each maximal ideal, then $(J:f)$ is not contained in any maximal ideal which is possible only if $(J:f) = A$; equivalently, if $f\in J$. Applied to each element of $I$ separately this implies that if $I_m\subset J_m$ for each maximal ideal $m\subset A$, then $I\subset J$.